# VBA .Find Changing Arguments Dynamically

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have a VBA function that uses the the .find method.  In my function I'd like change the LookAt: argument between xlPart or xlWhole.  I tried using a parameter variable matchvalue and passing in "xlPart" or "xlWhole".   It didn't work.

Is there a way to change the LookAt: argument with a variable I pass into my function?

```
Public Function getfield(matchvalue as string)

GetRowNumber = Cells.Find(What:="Cat", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _

        matchvalue, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _

        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
 End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the way you are splitting the lines makes you can't achieve your goal.

Try with:

```
Public Function getfield(matchvalue as string)

GetRowNumber = Cells.Find(What:="Cat", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=matchvalue, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
 End Function
```

Reading `.Find` documentation, LookAt value should be `Variant` Type.
Read the following link.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Comment: thank you.  Changing matchvalue from string to variant did it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your function is intended to return, but here's how I'd probably handle this:

```
Public Function getfield(Optional matchWholeValue as Boolean = True)

    GetRowNumber = Cells.Find(What:="Cat", After:=ActiveCell, _
                              LookIn:=xlValues, _         
                              LookAt:= IIf(matchWholeValue, xlWhole, xlPart), _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
End Function
```

To match on the whole value use:

```
  getfield()
```

and to match on part:

```
  getfield(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Public Function GetRowNumber(byval matchvalue as string, optional byval LookAtWhole = True) as long

Dim Result as range
Set Result = 
Activesheet.Cells.Find(What:=matchvalue After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlvalues, LookAt:=iif(LookAtWhole,xlwhole,xlpart), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _ , SearchFormat:=False)

If not (Result is nothing) then
Getrownumber = result.row
Else
Getrownumber = 0
End if

End Function
```

This function performs FIND method on active sheet's cells. Returns 0, if the criteria returned no results -- else the row number. You could add further parameters.

Hopefully it works and is what you wanted?